# Blackjack game with database - follow-up

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, mysql, playing-cards

This is a follow-up to my ex-posted Blackjack game that uses a MySQL database to store the accounts and user's money. I tried splitting `display_info()` a bit, I also added a check for validating the Email address and the passwords are now hashed.

```
from random import shuffle
import os
import cymysql
from getpass import getpass
import sys
import re
from bcrypt import hashpw, gensalt


def shuffled_shoe():
    shoe = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K']*4
    shuffle(shoe)
    return shoe


def deal_card(shoe, person, number):
    for _ in range(number):
        person.append(shoe.pop())


def deal_hand(shoe, player, dealer):
    for _ in range(2):
        deal_card(shoe, player, 1)
        deal_card(shoe, dealer, 1)


def score(person):
    non_aces = [c for c in person if c != 'A']
    aces = [c for c in person if c == 'A']
    total = 0
    for card in non_aces:
        if card in 'JQK':
            total += 10
        else:
            total += int(card)
    for card in aces:
        if total <= 10:
            total += 11
        else:
            total += 1
    return total


def set_money(money, money_bet, win, push):
    if win:
        money += money_bet * 2
    elif push:
        money += money_bet
    return money


def clear_console():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


def display_info(still_playing, player, dealer, money, money_bet, player_stands):
    win = False
    push = False
    clear_console()
    print(f"Money: ${money}")
    print(f"Money bet: ${money_bet}")
    print("Your cards:   [{}] ({})".format(']['.join(player), score(player)))
    if player_stands:
        print("Dealer cards: [{}] ({})".format(']['.join(dealer), score(dealer)))
    else:
        print("Dealer cards: [{}][?]".format(dealer[0]))
    first_hand = len(dealer) == 2
    if score(player) == 21:
        print("Blackjack! You won")
        still_playing = False
        win = True
    elif first_hand and score(dealer) == 21:
        print("Dealer got a blackjack. You lost!")
        still_playing = False
    elif score(player) > 21:
        print("Busted! You lost!")
        still_playing = False
    if player_stands:
        if score(dealer) > 21:
            print("Dealer busted! You won")
            win = True
        elif score(player) > score(dealer):
            print("You beat the dealer! You won!")
            win = True
        elif score(player) < score(dealer):
            print("Dealer has beaten you. You lost!")
        else:
            print("Push. Nobody wins or losses.")
            push = True
        still_playing = False
    money = set_money(money, money_bet, win, push)
    return still_playing, money


def hit_or_stand():
    while True:
        print("What do you choose?")
        print("[1] - Hit")
        print("[2] - Stand")
        ans = input('> ')
        if ans in '12':
            return ans


def bet(money):
    clear_console()
    print(f"Money: ${money}")
    print("How much money do you want to bet?")
    while True:
        money_bet = int(input('> '))
        if money_bet <= money and not money_bet <= 0:
            money -= money_bet
            return money, money_bet
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid bet.")


def player_play(shoe, player, dealer, money, money_bet, player_plays, player_stands):
    while not player_stands:
        if hit_or_stand() == '2':
            player_stands = True
            player_plays = False
        elif not player_stands:
            deal_card(shoe, player, 1)
            display_info(True, player, dealer, money, money_bet, player_stands)
            if score(player) >= 21:
                player_plays = False
                break
    return player_plays, player_stands


def dealer_play(shoe, dealer, dealer_minimum_score):
    while score(dealer) <= dealer_minimum_score:
        deal_card(shoe, dealer, 1)
    return False


def check_money(money):
    if money == 0:
        print("\nUnfortunately you don't have any money.")
        sys.exit()


def update_db_money(cur, money, email):
    cur.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `money`=%s WHERE `email`=%s", (money, email))
    cur.close()


def play_again(cur, money, email):
    check_money(money)
    while True:
        print("\nDo you want to play again? [Y]es/[N]o")
        ans = input("> ").lower()
        if ans == 'y':
            return True
        elif ans == 'n':
            update_db_money(cur, money, email)
            return False


def get_user_info():
    while True:
        email = input("Email address (max. 255 chars.): ")
        password = getpass("Password (max. 255 chars.): ").encode('utf-8')
        hashed_pw = hashpw(password, gensalt())
        if len(email) < 255 and len(password) < 255:
            if re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
                return email, password, hashed_pw
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid email address.")


def register(cur, email, hashed_pw):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`Email`, `Password`) VALUES (%s, %s)", (email, hashed_pw))


def login(cur, email, password, hashed_pw):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=%s LIMIT 1", (email,))
    correct_credentials = cur.fetchone()
    correct_hash = correct_credentials[2].encode('utf-8')
    if hashpw(password, correct_hash) == correct_hash:
        print("You've succesfully logged-in!")
    else:
        print("You failed logging-in!")
        sys.exit()


def check_account(cur, email):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=%s LIMIT 1", (email,))
    return bool(cur.fetchone())


def start():
    print("\nDo you want to start playing? [Y]es/[N]o")
    ans = input('> ').lower()
    if ans == 'y':
        return True
    elif ans == 'n':
        return False


def db_conn():
    conn = cymysql.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        user='root',
        passwd='',
        db='blackjack'
    )
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        email, password, hashed_pw = get_user_info()
        checked = check_account(cur, email)
        if checked:
            login(cur, email, password, hashed_pw)
        else:
            register(cur, email, hashed_pw)
            print("You've succesfully registered and recieved $1000 as a gift!")
        cur.execute("SELECT `money` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s", (email,))
        money_tuple = cur.fetchone()
        money = money_tuple[0]
        check_money(money)
        return cur, money, email


def main():
    cur, money, email = db_conn()
    keeps_playing = start()
    while keeps_playing:
        shoe = shuffled_shoe()
        player = []
        dealer = []
        still_playing = True
        player_plays = True
        player_stands = False
        money, money_bet = bet(money)
        deal_hand(shoe, player, dealer)
        still_playing, money = display_info(still_playing, player, dealer, money, money_bet, player_stands)
        while still_playing:
            while player_plays:
                player_plays, player_stands = player_play(shoe, player, dealer, money, money_bet, player_plays, player_stands)
            still_playing = dealer_play(shoe, dealer, 17)
        still_playing, money = display_info(still_playing, player, dealer, money, money_bet, player_stands)
        keeps_playing = play_again(cur, money, email)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Blackjack.sql:

```sql
SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `money` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Don't materialize generators unless you have to

These:

```
non_aces = [c for c in person if c != 'A']
aces = [c for c in person if c == 'A']
```

take up memory, however inconsequential. Since you only iterate through them once, change the `[]` brackets to `()` parens to leave it as a generator.

### Choose a quote standard

You have both single and double:

```
    print("[2] - Stand")
    ans = input('> ')
```

Choose one and stick with it.

### Redundant else

```
        return money, money_bet
    else:
```

doesn't require an `else`, because you've already returned.